# Readdir/closedir - Valgrind shows "invalid read"

Tags: c, linux, valgrind, readdir

Posting snippets of my code here. I am trying to get a footing around debugging.

```
struct dirent *s_dirent;
char path[300];
....
bzero(path,300);
...
fd_dir = opendir(path);
while((s_dirent = readdir(fd_dir))!=NULL)
{
     if(s_dirent->d_name[0] == '.')
          continue;
     else
          break;
 }
if(s_dirent == NULL)
{
   if(closedir(fd_dir)!=0)
       perror("Error on closedir");
 }
else
{

  if(closedir(fd_dir)!=0)/*Line number 249*/
      perror("Error on closedir");

  /*some comments*/
  strcat(path,"/");
  strcat(path,s_dirent->d_name);/*Line number 254*/
 }
```

Valgrind output:

```
==3287== Invalid read of size 1
==3287==    at 0x40069E0: strcat (mc_replace_strmem.c:176)
==3287==    by 0x804D6B4: online_bck (backup_manager.c:254)
==3287==    by 0x8049F96: on_bck_beg (TxFS_manager.c:181)
==3287==    by 0x8049818: handler (Reader.c:236)
==3287==    by 0xBF5F18: start_thread (in /lib/libpthread-2.12.90.so)
==3287==    by 0xB37A2D: clone (in /lib/libc-2.12.90.so)
==3287==  Address 0x402a39b is 35 bytes inside a block of size 32,792 free'd
==3287==    at 0x40057F6: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:325)
==3287==    by 0xAF6C67: closedir (in /lib/libc-2.12.90.so)
==3287==    by 0x804D65A: online_bck (backup_manager.c:249)
==3287==    by 0x8049F96: on_bck_beg (TxFS_manager.c:181)
==3287==    by 0x8049818: handler (Reader.c:236)
==3287==    by 0xBF5F18: start_thread (in /lib/libpthread-2.12.90.so)
==3287==    by 0xB37A2D: clone (in /lib/libc-2.12.90.so)
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Am very sorry to not have posted greater part of the code. Have done it now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not access data, returned by `readdir()` after calling a `closedir()`. This is because `closedir()` may free any resources (e.g. memory), allocated in opendir/readdir.

If you want to save dirent* struct, you can switch to `readdir_r` variant of readdir (with different set of parameters).

UPDATE: Decoding of Valgrind output:

```
        V - note single space here; it is beginning of error message. 
==3287== Invalid read of size 1
==3287==    at 0x40069E0: strcat (mc_replace_strmem.c:176)

 backtrace skipped
```

Valgrind says that error is `Reading of invalid data, sized 1 byte`, which is not a Memory Leak. It is incorrect memory access. And the actor of this read is the `strcat()` (called by skipped backtrace). Why the data is invalid? There is submessage

```
        VV - note two spaces here, it is continuation of error message
==3287==  Address 0x402a39b is 35 bytes inside a block of size 32,792 free'd
==3287==    at 0x40057F6: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:325)
==3287==    by 0xAF6C67: closedir (in /lib/libc-2.12.90.so)
```

The byte is invalid (not allowed to be read from) because it is part of memory segment which was free-d (you can't read from the memory you just free-d). Whom did this? Look at backtrace: `closedir` was the caller of free.

Comment: or maybe copy it else where before calling closedir()

Comment: Yes, but readdir_r will place dirent to user-supplied buffer directly, without copy. I should say, that my answer is pure speculation, and neither of Linux, SUS, Solaris man pages of readdir/closedir describes your case. But Valgrind output says, that strcmp trys to access a free-d data and closedir the only who can free it.

Comment: While what you say sounds plausible, neither the readdir() or closedir() man pages mention that the static buffer pointer returned by readdir() is deallocated by closedir().  Looking at the call stack where it was freed, it does look like that is what happened:  `at 0x40057F6: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:325)` called from `by 0xAF6C67: closedir (in /lib/libc-2.12.90.so)`

Comment: or move the closedir to after the strcat()?

Comment: Man pages were read by me BEFORE posting. This is a BUG of glibc, because the implementation limit was not documented.

Comment: IBM documents this: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=%2Fapis%2Fclosedir.htm " closedir() ... frees the buffer that readdir() uses when reading the directory stream."

Comment: Appreciate the detailed explanation @osgx

Comment: @Stéphane: I can't find anywhere POSIX documents that `closedir` may free the buffer returned by `readdir`, but that seems to be a defect in POSIX. It's obviously their intent that the buffer be in the `DIR` structure since a call to `readdir` for one open `DIR` is not allowed to clobber the `dirent` returned by a call to `readdir` for a different `DIR`. There is no way to meet these requirements without leaking memory unless `closedir` frees the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

`s_dirent == NULL`, check the `while` loop exit condition.

Comment: @Steave-o am sorry to not have posted the check for NULL that I had done before. But I had already checked for that condition. Thanks for your interest

Answer (score 0):

By the time you get to the `strcat()`, you've already exited the while loop.  The while loop exits once `s_dirent` is NULL.

But as soon as `s_direct` is NULL, you run this:

```
strcat(path,"/");
strcat(path,s_dirent->d_name);/*Line number 254*/
```

...which attempts to dereference s_dirent.  Thus, valgrind then tells you to check the call to strcat() being called from backup_manager.c:254:

```
==3287== Invalid read of size 1
==3287==    at 0x40069E0: strcat (mc_replace_strmem.c:176)
==3287==    by 0x804D6B4: online_bck (backup_manager.c:254)
```

I'm guessing you're hitting this only when you're processing an empty directory which contains entries for ".", "..", or directories that only contain hidden files which start with "."?

Comment: am sorry to not have posted the check for NULL that I had done before. But I had already checked for that condition and that is not leading to the error. Thanks for your interest